# A thesaurus that detects rhyming

Tags: tools, rhythm, thesaurus

I have been looking for a word that rhymes with post with similar meaning to a school.

But I go to thesaurus.com, sounding the words on my head for results under "school" and none rhyme. I then tried "academy" and failed to find anything.

But then I switched "post" for some other word to match "school", and nothing.

When I compared the alternatives for both choices, I decided on "set" and "department".

So is there a service that allows you to select two words (and its part of speech, just as here post was a verb and school was a noun) and give you combinations of rhymes?

P.S. If not, it shouldn't be too hard to create either.

> It's a program that retrieves your two words, inputs them into the thesaurus and tries to find a rhyme (requesting rhymezone.com) - and if it doesn't exist, then selects the first word from that list, re-iterates the program (but not for the new list, keeping it at n^2 complexity)...So, it should exist. Not very creative, I know.

Comment: Dunno if you can find a two-in-one solution, but you can search in the other direction with a rhyming dictionary, e.g. https://www.rhymes.net/ or https://www.festisite.com/poems/rhyme/

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! Take a look at our [tour] and [help] pages, while you're here. :)

Comment: You are correct it would not be difficult to build, but the data sourcing would require tremendous effort. You would need a thesaurus with full phonetics tailored to your personal accent...

Comment: This is probably a challenge for codegolf.SE

Comment: @NofP No. That's coding as short as possible.

Comment: @JossieCalderon not quite. Some of the challenges are about interesting problems, or fastest code, or bots that compete in an arena. In your case you have a graph matching problem between the graph of semantics, and the graph of phonetics...

Comment: @NofP Look what happened...-4 downvotes. Thanks https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/188777/a-thesaurus-that-detects-rhyming?noredirect=1#comment452098_188777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just stumbled upon

https://rhymebrain.com/en

Given a word it returns a section that suggests rhymes for related words. They may not synonyms, but it is the only tool I have found so far.

Comment: If I find a text file with a thesaurus and one with rhymes I'll gladly code your answer :)